# Function not showing up in plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have function that I wish to show on a plot, but it does not appear. Where did i go wrong?

(slutt means end in norwegian)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xstart = 1
xslutt = 5
ystart = 7
delta_x = 1
delta_y = 3

x = xstart
y = ystart

while x <= xslutt:
    plt.plot(x, y)
    print(x, y)
    x = x+delta_x
    y= y+delta_y
    

    

plt.xlabel('x - axis')

plt.ylabel('y - axis')
 
plt.title('My first graph!')
 
plt.show()
```

Comment: if i remember correctly you should pass arrays or lists to `plot`. (i.e. create `x=[...]` and corresponding`y=[...]` first and then call `plt.plot(x, y)`). see e.g. here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/introductory/pyplot.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may pass 1d arrays to `plot`, store the values in arrays then plot the line

```
xx, yy = [], []
while x <= xslutt:
    xx.append(x)
    yy.append(y)
    x += delta_x
    y += delta_y
```